Response from API not visible in TextView
I have made an android app and the data shows in the logcat for the API calls but it does not show in the textviews
Here is my MainActivity
package com.example.apicallapp;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import java.io.IOException;

import retrofit2.Call;

import retrofit2.Callback;
import retrofit2.Response;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TextView dataTextView;
    private TextView logTextView;
    private Button fetchDataButton;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        dataTextView = findViewById(R.id.dataTextView);
        logTextView = findViewById(R.id.logTextView);
        fetchDataButton = findViewById(R.id.fetchDataButton);

        fetchDataButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                fetchData();
            }
        });
    }

    private void fetchData() {

        logTextView.setText("Starting API call...");

        RetrofitClient.getApiService().getBasicData().enqueue(new Callback<BasicDataResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<BasicDataResponse> call, Response<BasicDataResponse> response) {
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    BasicDataResponse basicData = response.body();
                    if (basicData != null && basicData.getData() != null) {
                        dataTextView.setText(basicData.getData());
                        logTextView.append("\nAPI call successful: " + basicData);
                        showToast("Fetched Data: " + basicData.getData());
                    } else {
                        dataTextView.setText("No data received");
                        logTextView.append("\nAPI call successful: No data received." + basicData);
                        showToast("Fetched Data: " + basicData);
                    }
                } else {
                    String errorResponse = "";
                    try {
                        errorResponse = response.errorBody().string();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    dataTextView.setText("Failed to retrieve data");
                    logTextView.append("\nAPI call failure: " + errorResponse);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<BasicDataResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                dataTextView.setText("Error: " + t.getMessage());
                logTextView.append("\nAPI call error: " + t.getMessage());
            }
        });
    }

    // Method to display a Toast message
    private void showToast(String message) {
        Toast.makeText(this, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

Here is my ApiService
package com.example.apicallapp;

import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.http.GET;

public interface ApiService {
    @GET("api/basic/")
    Call<BasicDataResponse> getBasicData();
}

Here is my BasicDataResponse
package com.example.apicallapp;

public class BasicDataResponse {
    public String data;

    public String getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(String data) {
        this.data = data;
    }
}

Here is my Retrofit client
package com.example.apicallapp;
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;
import okhttp3.logging.HttpLoggingInterceptor;
import retrofit2.Retrofit;
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory;

public class RetrofitClient {
    private static final String BASE_URL = "https://6bf0-98-97-42-40.ngrok-free.app/";
    private static Retrofit retrofit = null;

    public static ApiService getApiService() {
        if (retrofit == null) {
            HttpLoggingInterceptor logging = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
            logging.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);

            OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
            httpClient.addInterceptor(logging);

            retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .client(httpClient.build())
                    .build();
        }
        return retrofit.create(ApiService.class);
    }
}


The logcat shows this
2024-05-27 11:01:35.647  6711-6730  EGL_emulation           com.example.apicallapp               D  app_time_stats: avg=9471.29ms min=1.48ms max=397533.56ms count=42
2024-05-27 11:01:35.887  6711-6791  okhttp.OkHttpClient     com.example.apicallapp               I  --> GET https://6bf0-98-97-42-40.ngrok-free.app/api/basic/
2024-05-27 11:01:35.887  6711-6791  okhttp.OkHttpClient     com.example.apicallapp               I  --> END GET
2024-05-27 11:01:35.953  6711-6791  TrafficStats            com.example.apicallapp               D  tagSocket(96) with statsTag=0xffffffff, statsUid=-1
2024-05-27 11:01:36.202  6711-6791  okhttp.OkHttpClient     com.example.apicallapp               I  <-- 200 https://6bf0-98-97-42-40.ngrok-free.app/api/basic/ (314ms)
2024-05-27 11:01:36.202  6711-6791  okhttp.OkHttpClient     com.example.apicallapp               I  allow: GET, POST, HEAD, OPTIONS
2024-05-27 11:01:36.202  6711-6791  okhttp.OkHttpClient     com.example.apicallapp               I  content-type: application/json
2024-05-27 11:01:36.203  6711-6791  okhttp.OkHttpClient     com.example.apicallapp               I  cross-origin-opener-policy: same-origin
2024-05-27 11:01:36.203  6711-6791  okhttp.OkHttpClient     com.example.apicallapp               I  date: Mon, 27 May 2024 18:01:35 GMT
2024-05-27 11:01:36.203  6711-6791  okhttp.OkHttpClient     com.example.apicallapp               I  referrer-policy: same-origin
2024-05-27 11:01:36.203  6711-6791  okhttp.OkHttpClient     com.example.apicallapp               I  server: WSGIServer/0.2 CPython/3.10.12
2024-05-27 11:01:36.204  6711-6791  okhttp.OkHttpClient     com.example.apicallapp               I  vary: Accept, Cookie
2024-05-27 11:01:36.204  6711-6791  okhttp.OkHttpClient     com.example.apicallapp               I  x-content-type-options: nosniff
2024-05-27 11:01:36.204  6711-6791  okhttp.OkHttpClient     com.example.apicallapp               I  x-frame-options: DENY
2024-05-27 11:01:36.204  6711-6791  okhttp.OkHttpClient     com.example.apicallapp               I  content-length: 247
2024-05-27 11:01:36.205  6711-6791  okhttp.OkHttpClient     com.example.apicallapp               I  {"status":"success","students":[{"id":1,"first_name":"Justin","last_name":"Ellis","address":"Renton","roll_number":460,"mobile":"1234567"},{"id":2,"first_name":"Hannah","last_name":"Angel","address":"Renton","roll_number":460,"mobile":"1234567"}]}
2024-05-27 11:01:36.206  6711-6791  okhttp.OkHttpClient     com.example.apicallapp              


But the android app itself says no data received
I was expecting it to show the get response

Your BasicDataResponse class is wrong. There is no field in the Json data.
create correct field like this
public class BasicDataResponse {
    public String status;


    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }
}


You have defined an incorrect POJO class to map the API response. You have to define your data models like this:
public class BasicDataResponse{
    public String status;
    public ArrayList<Student> students;
}

public class Student{
    public int id;
    public String first_name;
    public String last_name;
    public String address;
    public int roll_number;
    public String mobile;
}

Then in your ApiService
package com.example.apicallapp;

import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.http.GET;

public interface ApiService {
    @GET("api/basic/")
    Call<BasicDataResponse> getBasicData();
}

Then in your MainActivity, the fetchData method should be implemented like this:
private void fetchData() {

        logTextView.setText("Starting API call...");

        RetrofitClient.getApiService().getBasicData().enqueue(new Callback<BasicDataResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<BasicDataResponse> call, Response<BasicDataResponse> response) {
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    BasicDataResponse basicData = response.body();
                    if (basicData != null && basicData.students != null) {
                        //iterate through basicsData.students and display it on your text view etc. 
                    } else {
                        dataTextView.setText("No data received");
                        logTextView.append("\nAPI call successful: No data received." + basicData);
                        showToast("Fetched Data: " + basicData);
                    }
                } else {
                    String errorResponse = "";
                    try {
                        errorResponse = response.errorBody().string();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    dataTextView.setText("Failed to retrieve data");
                    logTextView.append("\nAPI call failure: " + errorResponse);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<BasicDataResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                dataTextView.setText("Error: " + t.getMessage());
                logTextView.append("\nAPI call error: " + t.getMessage());
            }
        });
    }


You can use this online JSON to POJO convert to generate data models from any JSON: https://json2csharp.com/code-converters/json-to-pojo
There are many extensions available for Android Studio as well which helps to generate these data models from JSON.

Note: You can also use the Gson annotations to represent the Student properties.
